# Angular Frontend CORS ERROR on POST request

Tags: angular, http, servlets, cors, xmlhttprequest

[image]
I am getting a CORS Error, when trying to POST onto my JAVA-SPRING backend. But GET-Requests from http://localhost:8080/api/currentPlayer are working.

Also I have added a

> Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header": "*" to the POST-Request.

I still get the Error, that this header is missing though. This is very confusing.

This is my Angular-Code from the service that makes the requests:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Player } from './Player';
import { Observable, catchError, map, of } from 'rxjs';
import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
import { HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { PlayerPost } from './PlayerPost';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PlayerService {

  constructor(private http: HttpClient,) { }

  private playerUrl = 'http://localhost:8080/api/currentPlayer';

  httpOptions = {
    headers: new HttpHeaders({
      'Content-Type':  'application/json',
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
    })
  };
  
  playerList: Player[] = [
    {
      "id" : 0,
      "name" : "Thorsten",
      "stack" : 5000
    },
    {
      "id" : 1,
      "name" : "Marietta",
      "stack" : 5000
    },
    {
      "id" : 2,
      "name" : "Rüdiger",
      "stack" : 5000
    },
    {
      "id" : 3,
      "name" : "Hans",
      "stack" : 5000
    }
  ]

  index: number = 0;

getPlayersObservable(): Observable<Player[]> {
    return this.http.get<Player[]>(this.playerUrl);
}

getPlayerList(): Player[] {
  this.getPlayersObservable().subscribe((x:Player[]) => {this.playerList = x;});
  return this.playerList;
}

postPlayer(player: PlayerPost) {this.http.post<any>(this.playerUrl, player, this.httpOptions).subscribe((res)=> console.log(res));

}

}
```

I have tried to declare Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header with "http://localhost:8080/api/currentPlayer".

I have added a Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header on the server-response.

EDIT: Below comment is right. I had to tell Spring to allow CrossOrigin. I did it with annotating the POST-Method with @CrossOrigin. I have followed the Tutorial on this site: https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service-cors.
I think if GET works and POST does not it indicates that the problem must be ServerSide.

Comment: You write: _I have added a "Access-Control-Allow-Origin Header": "*" to the POST-Request._ Just don't. `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` is a _response_ header, not a request header.

Comment: Okay. I took it out of the code. Nice Information :)

Answer (score 0):

CORS must be enabled on the server side for your requests to succeed

Comment: Thank you so much. I annotated the POST-Method in my REST-Controller with @CrossOrigin. That worked. Thanks again :))))